# time in java and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new with hibernate. I have an table in my DB (mySQL) with "startTime" column. It's type is time.
I downloaded org.joda.time package and use Period type, but this doesn't work and throws exception: 10954 `[main] ERROR org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - expected type: org.joda.time.Period, actual value: java.sql.Time`.

Which type should be the member in my java code?

Comment: I had to do this with joda-time and hibernate 4 recently, here is how http://stackoverflow.com/a/8989253/106261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should always store date and time in UTC in database. **java.util.Date** is what you should use as it represents the date and time in UTC and hibernate supports it.

Related post [How to store date/time and timestamps in UTC time zone with JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508019/jpa-hibernate-store-date-in-utc-time-zone)

If you only want to use joda-time then there are already converters written. You should use [Joda time - Hibernate support](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/index.html) library.

Comment: he wants to use joda time in tandem with hibernate so your suggestion would defeat the whole purpose

Comment: @MozenRath there is no real need to use Joda here

Comment: @MozenRath: I don't really want to use joda time since I just prefer to use the most suitable type for time.

Comment: I prefer to use joda-time, java date/calendar is an abomination

Comment: @NimChimpsky it is for data manioulations but it is not required for this simple case.

Comment: ohhk. I thought since you use joda time, you would want to handle all data as per joda time API

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate manages natively `java.util.Date` (and subclasses like `java.sql.Date`).

In order to use Joda Time object in your object model you can use the Joda provided [Hibernate types](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/index.html) for Hibernate up to version 3.6, and the [Usertype](http://usertype.sourceforge.net/) project for Hibernate 4.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a converter from java.sql.time to jodatime period and use it in your mapping. This happens because in the database it will always store value as java.sql.Time

Answer (score 0):

I have used LocalDateTime from joda package, and I have used "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDateTime" as the custom type in hibernate, and it works.
Am not sure , if this is what you are using.