# Set default Date in Hibernate and MySQL using @Before and xml file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I'm trying build a table with Hibernate + Spring and testing it with JUnit.

Here is my class model:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_name")
private User user;

@Id
@Column(name = "date_exam")
private Date dateExam;

@Column
private Float percent;
```

When I'm trying to testing it using JUnit:

```
@Test
public void testGetAll() {
    List<Score> scores = service.getScores();
    assertEquals(1, scores.size());
}
```

It shows this error (actually I tried with all the testing like Save, Update, Delete, Get A Record and same error occur):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'dateExam' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1362)
at org.dbunit.database.statement.SimplePreparedStatement.addBatch(SimplePreparedStatement.java:80)
at org.dbunit.database.statement.AutomaticPreparedBatchStatement.addBatch(AutomaticPreparedBatchStatement.java:70)
at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:195)
at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
at test.backend.config.dao.ScoreDaoTest.resetDatabase(ScoreDaoTest.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I think the problem with the `private Date dateExam;` the thing that I confuse is the column `dateExam` I set the default to `NULL` but why it said `SQLErrorException`. Before this, I already build 4 more tables but without `Date` as the column type and without error. I try to changed it to `private java.sql.Timestamp dateExam` but error still occur.

Anyone can give me solution for this?
I'm very appreciated with your help. Thanks...

**Update**

I try to remove the `@Id` and set the `nullable = true` but still the same...

**Update 30/04**

I got the problem, when JUnit testing I try to load the first data from xml file:

```
@Before
public void resetDatabase() throws Exception {
    IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File(
            "fixtures/score.xml"));
    final Connection conn = dtSource.getConnection();
    DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(new DatabaseConnection(conn),
            dataSet);
}
```

And the score.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
<user 
    user_name="crazenezz" 
    first_name="craze" 
/>
<score 
    user_name="crazenezz" 
    date_exam="2012-04-30" 
    percent="100" 
/>
</dataset>
```

The question now, **what is the true format for the date `date_exam` here using `java.util.Date` if we initialize the value inside the xml file**? Because I tried before to set the default value in the model `private Date dateExam = new Date()` the error still occur?

Comment: Date,DateTime and Timestamp are all supported by Mysql, check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

Comment: @AurA: I already update the question, got the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)` Hibernate annotation`(TemporalType TIME/DATE/TIMESTAMP)`, initialize the date.

Comment: Still problem occur. What do you mean with `initialize the date`? In the model or where?

Comment: @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateExam = new Date();

temporal annotation will be used to store date in TIMESTAMP or DATE or TIME

Comment: Hi, I already update the question, got the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

remove the id annotation for date(you can't have id value for two fields), to initialize you can just do this which give an initial date value.

```
@Column(name = "date_exam")
private Date dateExam = new Date();
```

But I would suggest using [joda-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8989253/106261)

Comment: Ok, let me try first using joda-time... Thanks for the response...

Comment: Hi Nim, I already update the question, got the source of the problem.