# get current date time in yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss format

Tags: java

I have an application which will ALWAYS be run in only one single time zone, so I do not need to worry about converting between time zones.  However, the datetime must always be printed out in the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss
```

The code below fails to print the proper format:

```
public void setCreated(){
    DateTime now = new org.joda.time.DateTime();
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss";
    created  = DateTime.parse(now.toString(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern));
    System.out.println("''''''''''''''''''''''''''' created is: "+created);
}
```

The setCreated() method results in the following output:

```
"2013-12-16T20:06:18.672-08:00"
```

How can I change the code in setCreated() so that it prints out the following instead:

```
"2013-12-16 20:06:18"
```

Comment: Don't you want `String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You aren't parsing anything, you are formatting it. You need to use [`DateTimeFormatter#print(ReadableInstant)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#print%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29).

```
DateTime now = new org.joda.time.DateTime();
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
String formatted = formatter.print(now);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

which prints

```
2013-12-16 11.13.24
```

This doesn't match your format, but I'm basing it on your code, not on your expected output.

Comment: Thank you. +1. But your code outputs a string.  Can you show me how to get it to output a datetime object?

Comment: @CodeMed Oh, then I believe you have a misunderstanding. A `DateTime`, `Date`, or whatever temporal object, doesn't have a format. You give it a text format when you output it. A `DateTime` `represents an exact point on the time-line, but limited to the precision of milliseconds.`

Comment: @CodeMed It has a default format in its `toString()` return value, but that again is just a textual representation. A date instant in itself is just the number of seconds/milliseconds since linux [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)).

Comment: Thank you.  I just want a SIMPLE way to pump this format into a MySQL TimeStamp field. I am stuck with hibernate and jpa for the application.  We have the correct format in your answer here.  I don't want to spend hours exploring complicated code when there has to be some simple way to force your correct syntax here into the database.  Do you have a simple suggestion?  See this other posting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625105/current-datetime-in-joda-time-date-formatting-for-mysql-timestamp/20625352#20625352

Comment: @CodeMed The MySQL date format you see when you play on the console is again just a textual representation of what it's actually storing which is just a bigint/long field (YMMV). At the JDBC level (the lowest level interface with your database), Hibernate is probably using [`setDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,java.sql.Date)). You need to find the joda-hibernate integration that will convert your `DateTime` object into a `Date` object internally, ie. this will be hidden from you.

Answer (score 4):

```
 public static void main(String args[])
{

SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");//dd/MM/yyyy
Date now = new Date();
String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
    System.out.println(strDate);
}
```

out put 2013-12-17 09:48:11

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");
        Date now = new Date();
        String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
        System.out.println(strDate);
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/oKqv51)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
org.joda.time.DateTime now = new org.joda.time.DateTime();
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
String formatted = formatter.print(now);
LocalDateTime date = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(formatted);
System.out.println(date.toDateTime());
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to offer an additional answer to this old question.

Answer (score 1):

And now in Java 9, you can use this:

```
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss"));
```