# hibernate 4 and joda-LocalDate and persist it as SQL Date

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974747/hibernate-4-and-joda-time) is almost what i am looking for but, it persists the LocalDate on my oracle db as Raw(255), so my question is how I can persist joda LocalDate to sql date?

Comment: Are you sure you want to persist a `LocalDate`? It does not contain timezone information...

Comment: yes, like birthday field.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally.

For my case, if I use org.jadira.usertype. somehow it persists the localdate as raw(255) on oracle.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR10</version>
    </dependency>
```

so if i change it to joda-time-hibernate, it seems working fine now, it persists as sql date.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```